# mountall problem on RAID

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, grub2, raid

I installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64 with a software RAID 1 and had to run boot-repair to make the system bootable. Now everything seems to be ok except that it throws following warnings during each boot:

```
swapon: /dev/disk/by-uuid/51a0d1be-d9d7-4d08-aebc-bddc25cdc4e5: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
mountall: swapon: /dev/disk/by-uuid/51a0d1be-d9d7-4d08-aebc-bddc25cdc4e5 [447] Terminated with status 255
mountall: Problem activating swap:  /dev/disk/by-uuid/51a0d1be-d9d7-4d08-aebc-bddc25cdc4e5
/dev/md0: clean, 12.../600... files, .../... blocks
```

As you can see in the [boot-info-file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5714342/), the partition mentioned above is the swap for both drives (sda1, sdb1) of the RAID array. fdisk -l also reveals some [errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5714337/). Couldn't find any applicable solution.

fstab content:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/md0 during installation
UUID=f6f13096-6514-4a5e-9fe9-151754c56b64 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=51a0d1be-d9d7-4d08-aebc-bddc25cdc4e5 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=51a0d1be-d9d7-4d08-aebc-bddc25cdc4e5 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Additional info: maybe it has something to do with the boot-repair warning `[dmraid] packages may interfere with MDraid. Do you want to remove them?` (I clicked No).

What can I do to resolve this? fsck?

Appriciate any help!

Comment: did you find a solution? I see the same message in boot-repair currently, unsure how to proceed..

Comment: @JonathanDay No I didn't, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

dumplicated entry in fstab:

```
UUID=51a0d1be-d9d7-4d08-aebc-bddc25cdc4e5 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

you should remove one of them, even though the comment has some difference.